# Is it possible to change the .aspx file during runtime in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in ASP.NET. I'm working on a web app whose client is a device with an embedded web browser. I need to create dynamic controls but so far they don't appear on the device's display. Somebody suggested that maybe the embedded browser doesn't support dynamic control use.

Finally, my question is: is there a way to simulate the creation of dynamic controls, perhaps by changing (if possible) the .aspx file during runtime to include Web server controls? Thanks in advance

Comment: you are not change the aspx file - you make a dynamic render of the page. look for tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It absolutely is possible. Years ago, I used to make "log" pages with a search user control at the top, but would write the log entries to the end of the file.

I used every browsers ability to recover from bad html to forgo closing the body and html tags.

Hence my page would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <uc:customcontrol />
        <div id="logs">
```

Leaving the html unfinished made for easy writing to the page.